# How to get animation as an image object

Tags: image, animation, scheme, racket

I can get animating images being shown using "universe.rkt" (https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpuniverse.html?q=universe.rkt) either with animate function or with big-bang.

However, how can I get these animations as image objects which I can place on canvas% objects (may be multiple times) as follows?

```
(define frame (new frame%
                   [label "Example"]
                   [width  500]
                   [height 500]))
(new canvas% [parent frame]
     [paint-callback
      (lambda (canvas dc)
        (send dc draw-bitmap (image->bitmap flowerImg) 20 20)  ; place image
        (send dc draw-bitmap (image->bitmap flowerImg) 200 200); place image
        )])
(send frame show #t)
```

The image->bitmap function is from https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-December/065110.html

```
(define (image->bitmap image)   
  (let* ([width (image-width image)]
         [height (image-height image)]
         [bm (make-bitmap width height)]
         [dc (send bm make-dc)])
    (send dc clear)
    (send image draw dc 0 0 0 0 width height 0 0 #f)
    bm))
```

The flowerImg is from: https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html

```
(define flowerImg
  (let ([petal (put-pinhole     
                20 20
                (ellipse 100 40 "solid" "purple"))])
    (clear-pinhole
     (overlay/pinhole
      (circle 30 "solid" "yellow")
      (rotate (* 60 0) petal)
      (rotate (* 60 1) petal)
      (rotate (* 60 2) petal)
      (rotate (* 60 3) petal)
      (rotate (* 60 4) petal)
      (rotate (* 60 5) petal)))))
```

Currently, I am using external programs to capture these animations as videos from screen and convert them to gif file, which I possibly can read as image and place on canvas.